# Why do the two codes have different execution time in Python?

Tags: python

I was solving a problem on an online judge website and I saw something strange.
When I submit the first code, I got a time-out error with an execution time of about 6000ms.
However, when I submit the second code, I got correct with an execution time of about 2400ms.
They look the same, but I'm not sure why these two codes have different execution times.

code1:

```
n,m = map(int, input().split())
data = dict()
for _ in range(n):
    a,b = input().split()
    data[a] = data.get(a,0) + int(b)
for _ in range(m):
    a = input()
    print(data.get(a,0))
```

code2:

```
n,m = map(int, input().split())
data = dict()
li = []
for _ in range(n):
    a,b = input().split()
    data[a] = data.get(a,0) + int(b)
for _ in range(m):
    a = input()
    li.append(data.get(a,0))
for i in li:
    print(i)
```

I searched about the difference between the two codes, but I didn't find out the reason why they have different execution times.

Comment: If anything code2 should be slightly slower. I can only assume the code provided doesn't match what was submitted or the site itself has an issue

Comment: You have 3 for loops vs 2 for loops. Each for loop iterates the whole array. If you do one more loop, it takes longer than not doing it.